# Double Nested(Multi-Level) Components Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, reactive-programming, angular-reactive-forms, dynamic-forms

I am trying to generate a dynamic form that will create a dynamic number of questions. I have a parent component, a child-list component, and a chill component which you can see below.
When trying to generate the page, I hit the error shown below.
note that it is rendering the first element and it fails on index 1.

Here is the parent template

```
<pif-question-list 
  [questions]="pifQuestions" 
  [parentFormGroupName]="prefundingForm">
</pif-question-list>
```

here is the child-list :

```
<div 
  class="question-container" 
  *ngFor="let question of questions;let idx=index;">
  <pif-question-detail 
    [question]="question" 
    [questionControls]='this.parentFormGroupName?.controls?.questions'>
  </pif-question-detail>
</div>
```

Here is the child :

```
<div 
  class="form-row" 
  formArrayName="answerTypes">
    <ng-container 
      *ngFor="let answerType of question.answerTypes;let idx=index;" 
      [formGroupName]="idx">
</div>
```

Here is the error:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find control with path: 'answerTypes -> 1'
    at _throwError (forms.js:1591)
    at setUpFormContainer (forms.js:1573)
    at FormGroupDirective.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.FormGroupDirective.addFormGroup (forms.js:4325)
    at FormGroupName.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.AbstractFormGroupDirective.ngOnInit (forms.js:1698)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:9042)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:10306)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:10268)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:10901)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:10861)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (QuestionDetailComponent.html:9)
```

Comment: Please post the structure of your Reactive Form so that it's a bit more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try it:
question.answerTypes.controls

Comment: Thanks! I was not looping through the controls. great help!!